# Squareful Part of a Family of Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, p-adic-number-theory, prime-factorization, perfect-powers

For any integer $x$, let $f(x)=64x^6-27$. Now, write $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$, where $g(x)$ is the *squarefree* part of $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ is its *squarefull* (*powerful*) part. For example, $f(5)=13^2\cdot 61\cdot 97$ and so $g(5)=61\cdot 97$, while $h(5)=13^2$. Note that $h(5)^2>g(5)$.

I would like to find a $\theta\in (1,2)$, maybe $\theta=3/2$ (?) for which $h(x)^{\theta}<g(x)$, for all integer $x\geq 5$.

To prove that, I tried to use LTE, since $\nu_p(64x^6-27)=\nu_p(4x^2-3)$, for all $3<p\mid 4x^2-3$. Also, I tried to combine Zsigmondy theorem, but without success.

I also stress that $f(x)$ is squarefree for about 90% of positive integers $x\in [6,300]$ and so the desired bound holds since, in this case, $h(x)=1$.

Any suggestions?

Comment: As a start:  $64n^6-27=(4n^2-3)(16n^4+12n^2+9)$ and $\gcd (4n^2-3,16n^4+12n^2+9)\in \{1,3\}$, so you can work with those two factors separately.

Comment: The only primes which can divide $64x^6-27$ are $p=3$ or $p\equiv\pm 1\pmod{12}.$

Comment: @lulu I noted this, but unfortunately I was not able to prove any useful fact with this observation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Yes, I know this. But it was not helpful to me yet. At least I don't know how to use this in my favour.

Comment: It seems $x=960$ provides a counterexample. We have $f(960)=3^3\times 11\times 13^2\times 73^2\times 661\times 283345969$ with $g(960)=3\times 11\times 661\times 283345969$ and $h(x)=(3\times 13\times 73)^2$. Turns out $h(960)^2=65697655057281\gt 6180625621797=g(960)$. A second check would be appreciated to ensure no calculation error.

Comment: Why are you interested in this specific polynomial?

Comment: @PrasunBiswas Thank you. I will check. Actually, the useful for me is any $1<\theta\leq 2$, for which $h(x)^{\theta}<g(x)$. So, the square power of $h(x)$ was only a bet.

Comment: @EricWofsey It is related to the discriminant of some elliptic curves I am interested in.

Comment: It would be useful if you put all you know in your question, so we don’t waste our time “helping” you with stuff you know.

Comment: My Python script found $n=960$ and $n=3861$ as counterexamples.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for the counter-examples. Could you please send me this Python script? In any case, maybe $h(x)^{3/2}<g(x)$ should work. I will edit question.